# Selecting Dashboard Frame in Tridion Anguilla Javascript

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I would like to select the frame hosting the 'Dashboard.aspx' page using the Tridion Anguilla JS framework.

Chrome detects 3 frames (with the last being the dashboard) and Firefox detects 2 frames.

Is it possible to refer to the dashboard frame other than the position in the frames array?

Chrome:

```
var dashChrome = window.top.frames[2]
```

Firefox:

```
var dashFF = window.top.frames[1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be wrong, but assuming you are working on Bookmarklet challenge :) here you go:
you can use View Id identifier, which is a `$display.getView().getId() == "DashboardView"`

And here is the bookmarklet:

```
javascript: (function (UI, B, e, a, r, d)
{
    try
    {
        while (r = UI.frames[e++])
        {
            if ((a = r.$display && r.$display.getView()) && a.getId() == B)
            {
                d = a;
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log(d);
    }
    catch (x) {};
})(window.top, 'DashboardView', 0)
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I'm taking a stab at the bookmarklet challenge.  Thanks to your code my solution is a lot less hackish than before :)

Comment: Nice arguments :D